# Laplace transform of Heaviside step function with trigonometric coefficient

Tags: laplace-transform, step-function

To compute the Laplace transform of the Heaviside step function, the function $f(t)$ in front of it has to be shifted to $f(t-c)$ for a Heaviside step function given by $u_c(t)$. In the case of $\cos (t)u_c(t)$ this can be done with the knowledge that $$\mathscr{L}\{\cos(at+b)\}=\frac{s\cos(b)-a\sin(b)}{s^2+a^2}$$however I am interested if there is another way to get functions of $t-c$ for cosine for the cases where this won't work. I have tried  a few methods with the addition formula but I always end up with $\sin(t)$ which obviously has the same problem (perhaps I'm not being imaginative enough).

Essentially this is a question on how to shift $\cos(t)$ into functions, $f(t-c)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you needing, something like $\cos(\pi - t)$?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Nothing in particular, I was just trying to think of a general way to think about/solve these problems when the transform of $\cos (at+b)$ can't be used.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the addition formula. Naturally this is how I'd tackle a problem like this.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Okay, that's good to know. But say we were trying use the addition formula in the case of $\cos (t)$, surely this ends up with a function of $\sin (t)$, which again would need to be evaluated?

Comment: I still don't quite follow. Do you want some way to remember the transforms of sine and cosine, even when it's something akin to $\cos(at + b)$? Or a way to avoid the addition formula?

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think I’ve been rather foolish here. Didn’t consider the fact that even though $\sin(t)$ isn’t in the form $f(t-c)$ it can easily be sorted out with the Laplace transform of $\sin (at+b)$. Thanks for your help :)